# How to run apache server if it not already running

Tags: linux, bash, apache-http-server, cygwin, shell-script

I wonder if it is possible to check whether or not apache2 is running. If it is not running I want to execute it using shellscript

Currently I have added a function which I named run_apache which simply goes to the directory with apache2 starts it. I have added this function to my `.bashrc` file. It will however execute everytime I open a new shell, which I don't want to unless apache2 is not running already.

Comment: what system are you running, Debian?

Comment: okay, I missed some tags. And missed also to mention it is about Cygwin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can easily get `apache2`'s status by launching

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 status
```

This will output one of these:

```
Apache2 is NOT running.
Apache2 is running (pid 10281).
```

It also happens to give you a valid return status, which you can use in a shell script (and discard its normal output with `> /dev/null`):

```
if /etc/init.d/apache2 status > /dev/null;
then echo "Apache already running";
else echo "Apache not running";
fi
```

I should add that there's no harm done from trying to start Apache when it's already running. So `/etc/init.d/apache2 start` will just say:

```
Starting web server: apache2httpd (pid 10281) already running
```

Comment: If you're on Cygwin, I have no idea how Apache is controlled there. From what my research tells me you can use `/usr/sbin/apachectl2 start` similarly to the usual `init.d` scripts in regular Debian-like Linux distributions.

Comment: Thanks anyway I solved it after getting some inspiration that I can use if condition. So I used the following condition for it `if ps aux | grep 'httpd2' -c > 0` which works for my usage. I'll mark this as accepted answer since I got an idea how to do from it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i know it's too late but someone can need it. I use cygwin with consoleZ.

1. First, open .bash_aliases file and add these lines


   `alias apacheup='cygstart --hide /g/xampp/apache_start.bat'
   alias apachedown='cygstart --hide /g/xampp/apache_stop.bat'
   alias mysqlup='cygstart --hide /g/xampp/mysql_start.bat'
   alias mysqldown='cygstart --hide /g/xampp/mysql_stop.bat'
   alias webup='apacheup && mysqlup'
   alias webdown='apachedown && mysqldown'
   alias webrestart='apachedown && mysqldown && apacheup && mysqlup'`
2. Second, in .bash_functions copy this function

   `webstat()
   {
       red='\e[0;41m'
       green='\e[0;42m'
       NC='\e[0m' # No Color

       if [[ -n $(ps aux -W | grep httpd.exe) ]]; then
           echo -e "Apache:\t"${green}" RUNNING "${NC}
       else
           echo -e "Apache:\t"${red}" STOPPED "${NC}
       fi

       if [[ -n $(ps aux -W | grep mysqld.exe) ]]; then
           echo -e "MySQL:\t"${green}" RUNNING "${NC}
       else
           echo -e "MySQL:\t"${red}" STOPPED "${NC}
       fi
   }`

Answer (score 0):

You could just add to your system's `/etc/rc.local` file your Apache startup command which would run it at the very end of the boot process.

There shouldn't be a need to check if it's running then because theoretically, it should stay running.